# Debugging 3rd party scripts with Aurelia

Tags: debugging, typescript, aurelia

I just started a new project using Aurelia and am unable to debug into a 3rd party plugin (`aurelia-auth` in this case) using Chromes Dev Tools.

I tried to debug into the plugin in order to understand why something I tried wasn't working and also to better understand the internals of the plugin a little better.

When I tried to debug into the plugin, the Dev Tools weren't able to jump to the correct sources but erroneously showed me some break points in my SCSS:

[image]

For reproduction purposes I've created a very simple CLI project with the following steps which behaves a little different but also not as expected:

- `au new` with the following options:
  `TypeScript`, `Sass`, `Testing Yes`, `WebStorm`, `Create structure` & `Install all dependencies`
- Adjusted `app.html` & `app.ts` (code below)
- Installed the [aurelia-auth plugin](https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth) using `npm install aurelia-auth --save`
- Added `aurelia-auth` & `aurelia-fetch-client` dependencies to `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` (code below)
- Started internal server using `au run --watch`
- Opened http://localhost:9000/ in chrome and opened dev tools
- Tried to debug into `auth.authenticate` which opens an empty file called `auth-service`

[image]

Is there anything I can do to improve this more than sub-optimal debugging experience? Also what is actually causing it? The aurelia framework itself, TypeScript, the CLI, ...?

---

Here's the simple code from the demo project:

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <button click.delegate="authenticate()">Auth</button>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
import {autoinject, Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AuthService, FetchConfig} from 'aurelia-auth';

@autoinject
export class Login {
    constructor(public auth: AuthService, public fetchConfig: FetchConfig) {
        this.auth = auth;
        this.fetchConfig = fetchConfig;
    }

    activate() {
        this.fetchConfig.configure();
    }

    authenticate(provider: String) {
        this.auth.authenticate(undefined, false, null);
    }
}
```

**aurelia.json**

```
{
    // ...
    "dependencies": [
        // ...
        {
            "name": "aurelia-auth",
            "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-auth/dist/amd",
            "main": "aurelia-auth"
        },
        "aurelia-fetch-client",
        // ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this possibly the same issue: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/342 ?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment It seems that those issues are indeed related. Thanks for pointing me at this issue!